# Fixing imageview frame according to image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am showing images downloaded from an URL in a table view whose custom cells have `UIImageView`s.

Now my requirement: I want to fix the height of that imageview and cell according to the height of that image in that cell.

Comment: after getting image from url i am getting sizes as image.size.height

Answer (score 1):

The steps to perform are the following: (I won't write the code for you, just guide)

1. in `heightForRow` method you pick the image from the data source
2. then you learn its size (image.size)
3. return the value like

   `size.height+SOME_CONSTANT`, where `SOME_CONSTANT` is the space for
   other content

Comment: i had done like that only butting getting problem this cell is hiding next cell

Comment: i got my by setting resolutions . Because images are in double resolution i am giving that size to frame so i got the problem now i am giving  half values as frame then i got correctly.
Thanks.